# react native get error Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project (react native version is 0.66.4) and it work well but now I want to change targetSdkVersion(30) and compileSdkVersion(30) to 31 when run the app it gets error Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. and even I have added android:exported= true to AndroidManifest part of <application / but it doesn't work

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // googlePlayServicesVersion = "4.3.3" // default: "+"
        // firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.0'
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
         repositories {
            configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.4"
            }
         }
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  
      }
}
```

/****************************
/app/build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {

    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
 
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mazeapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 20300
        versionName "2.3.0-googleplay"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
           
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    compile project(':react-native-audio-recorder-player')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

/************************

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"
      tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />


  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground (remote-only, for local use ignoreInForeground) -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false" />
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@color/white" /> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mazeapp.ir" android:pathPrefix="/app" />
        <data android:scheme="maze" android:host="payment" android:pathPrefix="/verify" />
        <data android:scheme="taraz" android:host="timer" android:pathPrefix="/link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="tarazapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/app" />
        <data android:scheme="taraz" android:host="payment" android:pathPrefix="/verify" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <service android:name="com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask" />

  </application>

</manifest>
```

/************

```
{
  "name": "mazeapp",
  "version": "2.3.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.12",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "4.0.4",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^2.6.4",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.2.0",
    "react-native-copilot": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "5.6.5",
    "react-native-emoji": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-file-picker": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.4",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-item-select": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalbox": "2.0.2",
    "react-native-motion": "1.0.5",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-persian-calendar-picker": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-progress": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-ratings": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-select-contact": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-modal": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "0.11.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
    "react-number-format": "4.4.1",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "victory-native": "^33.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-bundle-visualizer": "2.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Helloo,

Can you also share the error itself?

Answer (score 0):

you must added android:export= true or false in AndroidManifest.xml where there is  the tag intent-filter (anywhere) ofcourse you must add it to it's parent. for example

```
  <receiver android:exported="false"  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```